# Using itertools to group consecutive tuples by second value

Tags: python, tuples, python-itertools

I have a set of data in the form:

```
X1 = [(1,1),(3,1),(5,0),(3,0),(2,1)]
```

I can't figure out how to group them such that:

```
X2 = [[(1,1),(3,1)],[(5,0),(3,0)],[(2,1)]]
```

i.e. they are grouped in a consecutive fashion by the second value in each tuple.

I know it's something with this:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: why would you want to use itertools when there are easier ways?

Comment: @Ol'Reliable: Because your "easier way" does something different. What if the data is `[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (0, 0), (0, 2)]`?

Comment: what should the output be?

Comment: `[[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)], [(0, 0)], [(0, 2)]]`

Comment: ok ok, im sorry, i didn't quite fully understand the problem

Comment: No need to apologise man!

Grouping is dictated by the second value in each tuple.

eg. for X1 ignoring the first values these are (a,1),(b,1),(c,0),(d,0),(e,1)

Consecutive values that are equal are grouped:

((a,1),(b,1))((c,0),(d,0)),(e1))

Of course the second values could be anything... but they will always be grouped based on equal value and consecutive positioning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
X2 = [list(group) for key, group in groupby(X1, itemgetter(1))]
```

Pass a `key` function to `groupby` that fetches the second item of each tuple, so `groupby` groups the tuples by their second items.

Comment: ...Love the flexibility so I'll go with this. Well played!

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby, imap
from operator  import itemgetter

X1 = [(1,1),(3,1),(5,0),(3,0),(2,1)]
print map(list, imap(itemgetter(1), groupby(X1, itemgetter(1))))
# -> [[(1, 1), (3, 1)], [(5, 0), (3, 0)], [(2, 1)]]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
x = [(1,1),(3,1),(5,0),(3,0),(2,1)]
y = [x[n:n+2] for n in range(0, len(x), 2)]
print(y)
```

Comment: Functional and no modules required, smooth!