# grouping list of tuples with itertools

Tags: python

I am trying to group data based on second argument.

```
test= [(1,1),(3,1),(5,0),(3,0),(2,1)]
```

I am excuting code from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444728/using-itertools-to-group-consecutive-tuples-by-second-value)

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
result = [list(group) for key, group in groupby(test, itemgetter(1))]
```

But instead of getting a result that look like: 
 [[(1,1),(3,1),(2,1)],[(5,0),(3,0)]]

Why I am getting the last tuple in a seperated list, while I should get it grouped with other values where **1** is a second values

[[(1,1),(3,1)],[(5,0),(3,0)],**[(2,1)]**]

Comment: Because `groupby` groups only adjacent items. It is not equivalent to SQL's groupby.

Comment: Related: [How to group a list of tuples/objects by similar index/attribute in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602172/how-to-group-a-list-of-tuples-objects-by-similar-index-attribute-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has tripped me up in the past as well. If you want it to group globally, it's best to sort the list first:

```
In [163]: test = [(1,1),(3,1),(5,0),(3,0),(2,1)]

In [164]: crit = operator.itemgetter(1)

In [165]: test.sort(key=crit)

In [166]: result = [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(test, crit)]

In [167]: result
Out[167]: [[(5, 0), (3, 0)], [(1, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1)]]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a valid answer (I need to wait a little time in order to valid it (SO msg))